# SecurityToken null in Sonata Admin class

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I have a problem with getting the logged in user in and Admin class. What I would like to do is to restrict a choice field to logged in users organization (so that he is not able to pick another organization when creating an event). Therefore I've injected TokenStorage into my CalendarAdmin, but $tokenStorage->getToken() is null even if I'm logged in.
Here is my relevant code:

security.yml:

```
    providers:
    in_memory:
        memory: ~
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_manager

    admin:
        pattern:            /admin(.*)
        context:            user
        form_login:
            provider:       fos_userbundle
            login_path:     /admin/login
            use_forward:    false
            check_path:     /admin/login_check
            failure_path:   null
        logout:
            path:           /admin/logout
        anonymous:          true
```

services.yml:

```
    pozsonyba.calendar_bundle.admin.calendar:
    class: Pozsonyba\Bundle\CalendarBundle\Admin\CalendarAdmin
    arguments: [~, Pozsonyba\Bundle\CalendarBundle\Entity\Calendar, SonataAdminBundle:CRUD, @security.token_storage, @pozsonyba_organization.repository.organization_repository]
    tags:
        - {name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: admin, label: Calendar}
```

I read that this security.yml might have been set up wrong, that the firewall is missing something, I just can't figure out what.

Thank you for help.
CalendarAdmin.php:

```
    public function __construct($code, $class, $baseControllerName, TokenStorage $tokenStorage, OrganizationRepository $organizationRepository)
    {
        parent::__construct($code, $class, $baseControllerName);

        VarDumper::dump($tokenStorage->getToken());die;
        $this->organizationRepository = $organizationRepository;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the `\Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AbstractAdmin` class. You can get access to the container and the token storage via the configuration pool:

```
$this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer()->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser()
```

I guess, the token is not set when the admin object is created, so as an alternative way you can try to inject the `TokenStorage` via setter injection:

```
# CalendarAdmin.php
/** @var  TokenStorageInterface */
private $tokenStorage;

/**
 * @param TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage
 */
public function setTokenStorage($tokenStorage)
{
    $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
}
```

update services definition

```
# services.yml
pozsonyba.calendar_bundle.admin.calendar:
    class: Pozsonyba\Bundle\CalendarBundle\Admin\CalendarAdmin
    arguments: [~, Pozsonyba\Bundle\CalendarBundle\Entity\Calendar, SonataAdminBundle:CRUD, @security.token_storage, @pozsonyba_organization.repository.organization_repository]
    calls: 
        - [setTokenStorage, ["@security.token_storage"]]
    tags:
        - {name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: admin, label: Calendar}
```